# Experimental Design and Synthetic Cohort Methods

Tags: statistical-power, synthetic-cohort

I have a problem that I have not seen in the literature or discussed online. I am trying to design an experiment where there will be very few treated geographic units, perhaps only one. You can think of these as states of the US for the purpose of this question. I have historical panel data on both the outcomes and the covariates. In the non-experimental setting, synthetic cohort methods have been used to create Frankenstein control group(s) for causal inference. My situation is different since I can choose the treated unit(s). In doing that, there are several challenges that I am facing:

1. Is the SC method still the best way to approach this question?
2. How to do power calculation via simulation, when the SC estimation takes a considerable amount of time?
3. What criteria should be used to select the treated unit? Good RMSE between the treated and their SC on historical data? Lack of significant false positives in false placebo tests, when you vary the timing of the false placebo test?
4. When an additional unit gets assigned to treatment, it is pulled out from the set of potential donors, which alters how well the method works for the other treated units if that unit was heavily weighted and there is no suitable substitute.
5. If there are reasons to worry about spillovers between treated and control units, is there a way to make the selection process deal with this? In doing ordinary SC, I would often exclude nearby units from the set of potential donors.

Any advice of any of these points would be greatly appreciated. **I am especially interested in (2). My intuition is that if I take one treated state, change the outcome there by x% in the last k weeks in the historical data, perform the SC analysis on the altered data and obtain the joint p value using randomization inference, that is not quite correct since I cannot repeat this exercise multiple times.**

Cross-posted [on Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1420967-experimental-design-and-synthetic-cohort-methods) a few days ago.

Comment: I think your question would be improved if you could make clear ***what question(s) are you trying to answer using these methods?*** (i.e. w/r/t #2 power calculation for what kind of analysis?)

Comment: Eventually, I want to estimate the causal effect of treatment that happens in a single state. The canonical example is the effect of a tax on cigarettes levied by California on packs per capita purchased. This question is more about how to pick which state to tax and how to get a sense of minimum detectable effect for each potential state that could be treated.

Comment: The analysis will be done with synthetic cohort methodology.

Comment: Probably too late to ask, but why isn't individually randomized or cluster randomized trial not a possibility?

Comment: @Student I can't randomize individuals due to the general equilibrium effects/SUTVA violations. Cluster randomization is possible, though there could be some power issues with only 1 cluster in treatment.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ... yes, you would need to "treat" more than one cluster but I thought that you alluded to that possibility ... also, are you able to observe individual-level covariates and outcomes (or only at the cluster-level)? Finally, how many clusters do you have?